# Is there any way to install all the packages at once in MikTex package manager?

Tags: miktex

Every time I compile some files. I always need to add some specific packages. Some times, the Winedit will tell me which .sty file is missing yet the corresponding package name is not the same. Then I need to check on Google to find out its package name. So I wanna ask is there any way to install all the packages at once in MikTex package manager? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Why don't you want to use install-on-the-fly regime? Run MikTeX Console -> Settings -> Always install missing packages on-the-fly.

Comment: Yep! I mean I have selected install missing packages on the fly. But:  Some times, the Winedit will tell me which .sty file is missing yet the corresponding package name is not the same. Then I need to check on Google to find out its package name.

Comment: @Frank that isn't supposed to happen, the idea is that if latex finds a missing file miktex knows what to install. Personally I use texlive where installing everything is the norm and it does not do on the fly installation, but in either case you should not need to be searching for pacakge names in google

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For example, WinEdit told me that expl3.sty is missing. And MikTex didn't successfully find and install this. Since it couldn't find the package. Then I searched on Google just to find out that this expl3.sty is in the l3kernel package...

Answer (score 4):

Go to the miktex console to the package tab. Update the package base by clicking on 1. Sort the list by the installation date (2), select all (or a bunch if there are many) not installed packages, then click on the plus (3) to install them all.

[image]