# How Can I install Arabic package in MikTex?

Tags: miktex, arabic

when I try to type with Arabic I get errors. I found Arabic was not installed. herewith image illustrate  this.
thank all of you.
[image]

Comment: So did you install? It doesn't show that you installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install a package on MikTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484084/how-can-i-install-a-package-on-miktex) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529112.

Answer (score 2):

- This might help :).
- Try to follow the instructions from the [MiKTeX FAQ](https://miktex.org/faq/total-miktex).
- In this case, a simple Google search might have saved you from posting a question.

[image]